# Sublime Text 3 not picking up styles to auto-suggest

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, package, sublimetext3

I'm new to Sublime text.

Just to make sure we're all on the same page, the browser can see the styles and the site looks correct and as I've planned in a browser, but somehow, when you link to a custom or any, even cdn bootstrap stylesheet, you would expect Sublime Text to pick the styles up and "autosuggest". But it doesn't.

I have managed to install the bootstrap 3, emmet and better completion packages with no luck. Yes, I've restarted sublime text too.

Is there any other package I should install? Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Comment: "you would expect Sublime Text to ..." -- first rule about using ST: you don't expect it to do anything. You install plugins and pray that they work as expected.

Comment: Got your point ;-) As I said, I'm new to it. Will obviously have to learn to search the plugin repository better.

Comment: Oh yeah, let me rephrase the previous comment: ST is a very fast editor, and mostly just that. It is regarded as a "good" code editor mostly due to its rich plugins ecosystem which allows you to customize it to better suit your needs. Most of the IDE-like functionality such as your requested one is usually available in the form of plugins. By the way, install the [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) if you haven't yet. `;)`

Comment: Thanks, I did that. And I'm seriously considering going from Dreamweaver to Sublime Text, love it.